# Black box behind the video in Chrome 67.0.3396.87

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webrtc

On the page there is a HTML tag Video, which broadcasts the video from the interlocutor (WebRTС).

```
<div id="remoteVideoContainer">
    <video id="remotevideo" autoplay="autoplay" controls="" loop="loop" preload="true" 
height="500" width="100%">
    </video>
</div>
```

And css related to this part:

```
video {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

After upgrading Chrome to version 67.0.3396.87, I had a very strange bug - a black box (or two) whose size is depending on the size of the window (for some sizes it disappears). There is also a hole in full screen mode. What could be the problem? 
Here is inline mode:
[image]

And here is full screen:
[image]

In earlier versions of Chrome there was no such problem. It also does not exist in other browsers.

Comment: Does it happen with any video file? Also, [the `width` attribute cannot use percentages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)

Comment: Play your video then in developer tools click the console tab. In the command line type: `var vid = document.getElementById('remotevideo');` then enter/return key. Next `vid.videoWidth` Enter. Then `vid.videoHeight` Enter. What are the dimensions reported in console?

Comment: Or better yet, include the real video in the code itself. Use an absolute url (ex.`https://example.com/path/to/vid.mp4`) a relative url is useless (ex.`/path/to/vid.mp4`)

Comment: Please provide code that reproduces the issue as this is not something I have been able to replicate.

Comment: Can u please share the code snippet here, so that the issue can be reproduced to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create video element not from HTML but from JS. For example:

```
var el = document.createElement('video');
el.setAttribute('controls', 'true');
....
```

I think its helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting, on the latest chrome canary build and can't replicate this issue. The only solution you have is to wait for the next chrome update. The problem isn't in your code, it's on the browser that I can guarantee is fixed in the upcoming update.

Answer (score 0):

Like Sethu says, it seems to be chrome, not your code.
Is there a chrome beta build you could try which might have a fix by now?
If not maybe you could roll back to the previous chrome version.